# how to encrypt string using AES 128 bit in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle, security, aes

im working on webapplication in asp.net with oracle Database12c
im using aes128 stored procedure to encrypt the password
here is the procedure that makes encryption

```
DECLARE
   l_user_id    test.username%TYPE := 'SCOTT';
   l_user_psw   VARCHAR2 (2000) := 'mypassword123';

   l_key        VARCHAR2 (2000) := '1234567890999999';
   l_mod NUMBER
         :=   DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128
            + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
            + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
   l_enc        RAW (2000);
BEGIN
   l_user_psw :=
      DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt (UTL_I18N.string_to_raw (l_user_psw, 'AR8MSWIN1256'),
                           l_mod,
                           UTL_I18N.string_to_raw (l_key, 'AR8MSWIN1256'));
   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Encrypted=' || l_user_psw);

   INSERT INTO test VALUES (l_user_id, l_user_psw);
dbms_output.put_line('done');
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

and the final result is

```
132BEDB1C2CDD8F23B5A619412C27B60
```

now i want to make identical Aes in c#
i know i can call stored procedure from c# and get the same result
but i want to make it using c# for security reasons
i have tried many ways but ended up with different result !
i need help please !

Comment: I've removed the `[asp.net]` tag because this question isn't related to ASP.NET.

Comment: _"i have tried many ways but ended up with different result"_ - you would do well to show those attempts.

Comment: system.security.cryptography.aes [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netcore-3.1#examples) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm feeling generous, I'll provide a solution for you:

```
public static string EncryptPassword(string key, string password)
{
    // Your current code uses WIN1256 encoding for converting
    // your strings to bytes, so we'll use that here
    var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
    byte[] passwordBytes = encoding.GetBytes(password);
    byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);

    using (var aes = AesManaged.Create())
    {
        // Set up the algorithm
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Key = keyBytes;
        aes.BlockSize = 128; // AES-128
        // You don't specify an IV in your procedure, so we
        // need to zero it
        aes.IV = new byte[16];

        // Create a memorystream to store the result
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // create an encryptor transform, and wrap the memorystream in a cryptostream
            using (var transform = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                // write the password bytes
                cs.Write(passwordBytes, 0, passwordBytes.Length);
            }
            
            // get the encrypted bytes and format it as a hex string and then return it
            return BitConverter.ToString(ms.ToArray()).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/LZIQB47916)